# Airflow dags lifecycle events

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to manage airflow dags (create, execute etc.) via java backend. Currently after creating a dag and placing it in dags folder of airflow my backend is constantly trying to run the dag. But it can't run it until its picked up by airflow scheduler, which can take quite some time if the number of dags are more. I am wondering if there any events that airflow emits which I can tap to check for new dags processed by scheduler, and then trigger, execute command from my backend. Or is there a way or configuration where airflow will automatically start a dag once it processes it rather than we triggering it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way or configuration where airflow will automatically start a dag once it processes it rather than we triggering it ?

Yes, one of the parameters that you can define is `is_paused_upon_creation`.

If you set your DAG as:

```
DAG(
    dag_id='tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=datetime(2020, 12, 28),
    is_paused_upon_creation=False
)
```

The DAG will start as soon as picked up by the scheduler (assuming conditions to run it are met)

> I am wondering if there any events that airflow emits which I can tap to check for new dags processed by scheduler

In Airflow >=2.0.0 you can use the API - [list dags endpoint](http://%20I%20am%20wondering%20if%20there%20any%20events%20that%20airflow%20emits%20which%20I%20can%20tap%20to%20check%20for%20new%20dags%20processed%20by%20scheduler) to get all dags that are in the dagbag

In any Airflow version you can use this code to list the dag_ids:

```
from airflow.models import DagBag
print(DagBag().dag_ids())
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. After your answer I found that in configuration as well we can add a change to make the dags run by default. Now the second part , though I can get list if dags and check whether the dag I created exists or not. But the problem statement is I don't want to keep on checking from backend side. I am looking for something which is triggered by airflow side.

Comment: As we know that airflow also maintains the entries in database , so there should be something which adds that entry into database after its picked up by airflow. But don't know if we can listen or track that event/process idk..