# Apache Airflow not running any task

Tags: python, airflow

Downloaded the docker-compose from the official website:

```
curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.0/docker-compose.yaml'
```

Executed the command:

```
docker-compse up airflow-init
```

And then

```
docker-compose up -d
```

All the docker containers are healthy:

```
           Name                          Command                  State                         

    Ports                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
airflow_airflow-init_1        /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Exit 0                                                           
airflow_airflow-scheduler_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (healthy)   8080/tcp                                          
airflow_airflow-webserver_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,:::8080->8080/tcp          
airflow_airflow-worker_1      /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (healthy)   8080/tcp                                          
airflow_flower_1              /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp,:::5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp
airflow_postgres_1            docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up (healthy)   5432/tcp                                          
airflow_redis_1               docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp,:::6379->6379/tcp
```

I go to the UI launch **example_bash_operator**, it never ends, Ended is "not ended yet" for hours already, no error logs on scheduler, worker or webserver.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you turn ON the DAG?

Comment: Hi @JavierLópezTomás you were right, the DAGs were paused, please post as an answer and I will give it as valid, thanks!

Comment: You can avoid this by setting `is_paused_upon_creation` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65506288/14624409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you turn the DAG ON